# Split N-Values to N-rows using MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have the table training, I want to split Training_name Column values to multiple Rows:

```
SLNO Category Training_name
1     A        1,5,9,15,12,16
2     B        2,6,10,17
3     C        1,3,7,19,14,18
```

I used below Query but using this Query i can only split to 2 Rows only?

```
SELECT training.SLNO,training.CATEGORY, SubString_Index(training.TRAINING_NAME, ',', 1) AS TRAINING_NAME FROM training UNION ALL SELECT training.SLNO,training.CATEGORY, SubString_Index(training.TRAINING_NAME, ',', -1) FROM training
```

i am trying to get the table as given below,Please help me out

```
SLNO Category Training_name
1      A        1
1      A        5
1      A        9
1      A        15
1      A        12
1      A        16
2      B        2
2      B        6
2      B        10
2      B        17
3      C        1
3      C        3
3      C        7
3      C        19
3      C        14
3      C        18
```

Comment: not clear enough. you need help with a SELECT? Or you want to alter the schema?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: how many of those comma separated values can appear in the last column?

Comment: I upvoted the question because the OP wants to move away from CSV data in his table, which is a step in the right direction and the opposite of what we often see here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have used your Query given below, it works fine for splitting only two to Two Rows but i have 25 values in one column ? Is there any dynamic solution for SPLITTING 25 VALUES INTO 25 ROWS...I hope you got  my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option which will work well if every training name entry has two values separated by a single comma.

```
SELECT
    PARENT_SLNO,
    RNO,
    TRAINING_CATEGORY,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRAINING_NAME, ',', 1) AS TRAINING_NAME
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT
    PARENT_SLNO,
    RNO,
    TRAINING_CATEGORY,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRAINING_NAME, ',', -1)
FROM yourTable
```

If you want to convert your entire table, then you could select the above query into a new table, delete the old one, then rename the new one.  If your CSV data could have a varying number of commas then my query would need to be modified, but the general approach could remain the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...it works

Comment: Totally different question, totally different answer.  You should ask a new question in my opinion.

Comment: Continuation to the above Question,I have n values in 'TRAINING_NAME' field, How can i give Return all Rows

Comment: can you give me dynamic solution for the above query to split N-Values into N-Rows?

Comment: I think you would need dynamic SQL to handle an arbitrary number of commas.  Believe it or not, this is beyond my normal capabilities.

Comment: Can you please check now,i have edited my Question.pls check and give solution if there any possibility?

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't work this way.  Ask a new question.